# Sql Server - Comparing time only in 24 hour format?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to compare time with a time-range and if that particular time lies with-in that time-range, then it should return a record.

For example, Table 'A' has :

```
+-----------+------+-------------+-----------+
| User_Code | Name | Shift_Start | Shift_End |
+-----------+------+-------------+-----------+
|         1 | ABC  | 04:01:00    | 11:00:00  |
|         2 | DEF  | 11:01:00    | 20:00:00  |
|         3 | XYZ  | 20:01:00    | 04:00:00  |
+-----------+------+-------------+-----------+
```

Now I want to check whose shift was it at this specific datetime : `2016-09-26 02:51:59`. The SQL query should return the `User_Code = 3`. `Shift_Start` and `Shift_End` are of type `time`.

I have tried converting `2016-09-26 02:51:59` to time and then comparing with `shift_start` and `shift_end` using `between` and using `logical operator` but I am unable to get the desired result.

This has got me baffled. Its been an hour since I have tried coming up with a solution but I am unable to do so. Tried googling but got nothing there too. Any help will be appreciated. Using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: If you only want to deal with `TIME` and not `DATETIME`, it might make your life easier to split your `20:01:00 - 04:00:00 XYZ` range into two ranges: `00:00:00 - 04:00:00 XYZ` and `20:01:00 - 23:59:59 XYZ`

Comment: @paul, yes but I don't really wanna change DB structure but I agree this would make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a more complicated `where` condition, because the shift times can be in either order.

So:

```
where ((shift_start < shift_end) and
       cast(@datetime as time) between shift_start and shift_end)
      ) or
      ((shift_start > shift_end) and
       cast(@datetime as time) not between shift_end and shift_start)
      )
```

Comment: Thank you brother. I didn't realize that I could do 'not between' too.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, I know this is answered. but when I try to pass `@datetime = '2016-09-24 17:51:59'` it is giving 2 rows (2&3) instead one.

Comment: @user3583912 . . . The operators for `between` and `not between` need to have the lower value first.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table(
    User_Code int,
    Name varchar(20),
    Shift_Start time,
    Shift_End time
    );
insert @t(User_Code,Name,Shift_Start,Shift_End)
values
 (1,'ABC','04:01:00','11:00:00')
,(2,'DEF','11:01:00','20:00:00')
,(3,'XYZ','20:01:00','04:00:00');
```

Try

```
declare @d datetime = '2016-09-26 02:51:59';

select *
from @t
cross apply ( -- intermediate vars: rounded param 
         select dt = cast(cast(@d as date) as datetime)
            ) r
where @d between dateadd(d, case when Shift_Start<Shift_End then 0 else -1 end, dt) + cast(Shift_start as datetime)  
         and dt+cast(Shift_end as datetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach from the other angle and add the date part of your search criteria to the Shift Start and End Times:

Note the case statement, this handles the situation where the shift end crosses midnight.

```
 DECLARE @dateTime DATETIME = '2016-09-26 02:51:59'
 -- Remove the time portion of above
 DECLARE @datePortion DATETIME = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @dateTime)) 

 SELECT * FROM TableA 
   WHERE @dateTime BETWEEN @datePortion + cast(Shift_Start as datetime)
                    AND CASE WHEN ShiftEnd < ShiftStart
                           THEN DATEADD(day, 1, @datePortion)
                           ELSE @datePortion
                        END + cast(Shift_End as datetime)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't produce desired result.